# Map back to previous position after onRegionChange

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I'm using Expo MapView, and when I try to change the value of the indicated region in the onRegionChange, the map returns to the previous position. How fix this?

```
import React from 'react';
    import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
    import {
      Location,
      MapView,
      Marker
    } from 'expo';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      state= {
          region: {
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          },
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', width: '100%', zIndex: 0 }}
            onRegionChange={(region) =>this.setState({ region: region })}
            region={this.state.region}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because you are setting state that is passed to region props in `onRegionChange`,

`setState` takes its time to set the value and re-render component.

In between `onRegionChange` is called atleast 5-10 times.

Hence again 5-10 `setState`, so it is becoming laggy.

If you want to store current region then just use other state than `region`.

**EDIT**: actually using state can also be laggy right because after all it is again doing all the stuffs but now just name changed.

SO you might use normal variable instead of state.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with:

```
 onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => props.map.animateToRegion(region, 0)}
```